# Depth Test não está funcionando corretamente no OpenGL

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glsl

Estou tendo um problema com o `Depth Test`. Tenho uma cena onde contem três objetos. Um plano um cubo e um cilindro. No meu Render estou fazendo para quando for renderizar o cubo ele deve desativar o Depth Test. Com isso o cubo (na cor laranja) deveria sobrepor o plano (verde) e o cilindro (azul). Mas isso não acontece.

Render normal com Depth Test ligado e no modo GL_LEQUAL.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Render com Depth Test desligado somente para o cubo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O cubo esta sobrepondo o plano verde, mas não sobrepõem o cilindro azul.

```
void HOpenGLForwardRenderer::RenderOpaqueMesh(HGameObject* gameObject, HMaterial* material, HShader::HRenderPass pass)
    {
        gEngine = HEngine::GetInstance();

        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
        glCullFace(GL_BACK);

        glDepthMask(true);

        if (gameObject->mName == "Cube.1") {
            glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }
        else {
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        }

        glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

        glUseProgram(pass.gpuProgram);....
```

O que eu possa estar fazendo de errado? Estou utilizando OpenGL 2.1 e três shaders um para cada objeto mas com o mesmo código (só muda a cor).

```
    #version 120

    uniform mat4 HEngine_MatrixMVP;

    attribute vec3 in_Position;

    void main()
    {
        gl_Position = HEngine_MatrixMVP * vec4(in_Position, 1.0);
    }

    #version 120

    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(0.8, 0.4, 0, 1); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Se estou lendo teu código corretamente, parece que não está controlando a ordem em que renderiza as formas. Sem DEPTH_TEST, a ordem de renderizar importa. A forma mais nova ficará em cima.

Se o cilindro for renderizado depois do cubo e o cubo foi renderizado com DEPTH_TEST desligado, o cilindro DEVE ficar em cima. Se você que o cubo em cima, precisa ter certeza que renderizou o cubo último, depois de desligar DEPTH_TEST.

Se ainda não funcionar, tambem pode tentar chamar `glClear( GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT )` para jogar fora os dados de profundeza das otras formas. Mesmo assim, precisa renderizar o cubo último para ficar em cima.